# ViewBag values are not displaying in a select box?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

list of values in **ViewBag** and want to *display* this values in a **select box**.The values are coming inside of the view.But it isn't displaying .
**Codeblock:**

```
 <select name="postoffice">
       <option>-select-</option>
                    @if (ViewBag.s != null)
                    {
                       foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)
                        {
                         <option value="@f.po">@f.po</option>

                        }
                     } 
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast ViewBag.s in specific format before implement foreach loop (List) ViewBag.s